# Group Isomorphisms. Need clarification of question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $A,B,C$ be subgroups of a group $D$ such that $B,C \trianglelefteq D$ and $A=B\cap C$. Show that 
$$ \frac{D/B}{C/A} \cong \frac{D/C}{B/A}$$
My question is simply a clarification of what $\frac{D/B}{C/A}$ and $\frac{D/C}{B/A}$ are. Specifically, isn't the quotient group $\frac{D/B}{C/A}$ defined only when $C/A \trianglelefteq D/B$, but $C/A$ is not even a subset of $D/B$.

Comment: The inclusion of $C$ in $D$ induces a homomorphism from $C/A$ into $D/B$; the person posing the problem probably intended that you identify $C/A$ with its image under this homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be the composition of the following two maps:
$$C \xrightarrow{\;\;\text{inclusion}\;\;} D\xrightarrow{\;\;\text{quotient}\;\;} D/B$$
Note that $\ker(f)=B\cap C=A$, so by the first isomorphism theorem there is an **injective** induced map
$$C/A\xrightarrow{\;\;\text{induced}\;\;} D/B$$
The notation $\dfrac{D/B}{C/A}$ implicitly identifies $C/A$ with its image under this injective map.